# Yoast SEO only show on static pages

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

hello i have Yoast SEO installed in my wordpress it works fine in most pages i get this [image]

but on some pages (The important ones that are dynamic) it doesn't show the Snippet Preview Section it preview it empty without tabes even
  like this [image]

i ive been searching for days but with no luck
EDIT : 
i get this error on console in the pages that yaost don't work in other pages are fine [image]

Comment: Look for error messages in your console. Also, try disabling all the plugins except Yoast SEO and see if it works. If it does work, enable one plugin at a time and check when Yoast SEO stops showing up on this pages.

Comment: Thank you very much the preview section flashes once then disappear in the dynamic pages but works fine in the static pages where can i find the console?

Comment: i disabled every plugin except yaost but the problem still presists

Comment: You can view the javascript console in your browser's developer tools. Usually right clicking in an empty are and choosing 'inspect element" will open dev tools. From there, you should have a tab called "console". Keep that tab open and refresh the page. Check for errors in there. Also, since it's flashing, it looks like it's malformed HTML from the dynamic pages. What exactly do you mean by dynamic vs static pages in wordpress ? This is in the backend right ?

Comment: I mean by static posts,  and dynamic custom posts